# Killing "+" sign after incorrect syntax

Tags: r

After entering a complex code(where something was incorrect), instead of `>` sign R displays `+`. If I knew what is missing (oftentimes due to missing out `(`,`)`,`'`) it would be easy to fix, but I am not sure. Therefore I am "locked" with this `+` state and cannot escape it. Is there a way to kill it and revert back to the default prompt?

Comment: Just press `CTRL+C` on the keyboard, if you are running plain R. Some IDE (like RStudio) have a `Stop` button you can press to abort the command given.

Comment: @nicola thanks, that's it. if you put this as an answer, I will check it out as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where R is running. Try `CTRL+C` on the keyboard, if you are running plain R. Some IDE (like RStudio) have a Stop button you can press to abort the command given.

Answer (score 3):

Often `Esc`, the escape key works.

Comment: `Esc` did not help